# DataGridView Remove GridLines from first column

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm attempting to remove the gridlines on the first column in a datagridview so it looks like this:

[image: First Column without gridlines]

Unfortunately i've only managed to remove the lines on a row/cell basis but what i need is to remove the lines for the entire column but keep the right hand side line, is there a standard way of acheiving this?

Answer (score 1):

Following code must do what you want

```
        private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex > -1)
            {
                e.AdvancedBorderStyle.Left = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;
                e.AdvancedBorderStyle.Top = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;
                e.AdvancedBorderStyle.Bottom = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

One dirty-hack would be to recursively change cell styles on Datagridview Paint Event under the particular column. Use a for-loop to manipulate the cell border style.